# Nginx Security Configuration

Tags: security, ssl, nginx, nginx-config

I am kind of new to the configuration for the Nginx as a proxy for an internal web service, which is needed to be forwarded using SSL connections.

The setup currently involves to serve an internal web-application which is currently running on a public cloud infrastructure.

Below is my `nginx` configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name www.somedomain.com;
  # Refer:
  # https://www.nginx.com/blog/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-and-nginx/
  # Discourage deep links by using a permanent redirect to home page of HTTPS site
  return 301 https://$server_name;
}

server {
  # User Defined
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  # SSL Certificate Paths
  ssl_certificate /home/secured/ssl/certs/mycustomapp.cert;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/secured/ssl/private/mycustomapp.key;

  # Nginx Access and Error Logs
  access_log /var/log/nginx/mycustomapp.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/mycustomapp.error.log;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  # User Defined
  server_name www.somedomain.com;

  # HSTS header for always https option
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=36000; includeSubDomains" always;
  add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";

  location / {
    # User Defined
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9090;
    proxy_read_timeout 90s;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:9090 https://$server_name;
  }
}
```

Where I have generated a self-signed certificates for the server:`mycustomapp.cert` and corresponding key in: `mycustomapp.key`, and the local service/application is running on `http://localhost:9090` and is **not** running on global access port `0.0.0.0:9090`.

Here is the snippet of `access.log` available at this location `/var/log/nginx/`.

```
106.51.17.223 - - [23/Dec/2018:17:51:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
47.75.165.214 - - [23/Dec/2018:18:16:47 +0000] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "-"
47.75.165.214 - - [23/Dec/2018:18:16:47 +0000] "GET /webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
47.75.165.214 - - [23/Dec/2018:18:16:47 +0000] "GET /help.php HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0"
47.75.165.214 - - [23/Dec/2018:18:16:48 +0000] "GET /java.php HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0"
47.75.165.214 - - [23/Dec/2018:18:16:58 +0000] "POST /wuwu11.php HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
47.75.165.214 - - [23/Dec/2018:18:16:58 +0000] "POST /xw.php HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
47.75.165.214 - - [23/Dec/2018:18:16:59 +0000] "POST /xw1.php HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
47.75.165.214 - - [23/Dec/2018:18:16:59 +0000] "POST /9678.php HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
```

I have also observed some malformed requests in both the `access.log` and `mycustomapp.access.log`(not replicated here).

Is the configuration enough for delaying/thwarting these penetration attack attempts or is there a redundant configuration which is exposing a channel which currently I am unable to comprehend?

Currently I am enabling the service when someone requires an access, but going forward it is not a suitable scenario when more and more people start using the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration is enough as usual. For more security watch this list:

1. https://github.com/nbs-system/naxsi
2. Use [this](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) to opimize SSL performance.
3. Read about server_tokens and disable it.
4. Read about error_page and use your own pages.